# Best way to find matches in sheet compared to listbox vba

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, find, multiple-matches

I basically want to know what is the best way to compare items in a sheet to a listbox, basically, items in listbox need to be found on a sheet, if they are not found they need to go to the bottom of the sheet on the next free row,

This shouldn't be too hard but I've tried using and if statement but finds it has to search all of the rows on the sheet with all of the rows within the listbox which makes it laggy, time-consuming and unresponsive at times,

I was thinking of using the .find method but didn't want to waste my time,

Update of code:

`

```
          For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

            field1 = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
            field2 = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1)
            field3 = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2)


            field2ammend = Right(field2, Len(field2) - 7)


    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells






        If rCell.Value = field1 Then

            comp = field3
            name = field2ammend

            Sheets("Hair").Range("E" & rCell.Row) = comp
            Sheets("Hair").Range("F" & rCell.Row) = name

            Range("A" & rCell.Row & ":H" & rCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 24

            countgood = countgood + 1




        Else




            ListBox2.AddItem (field2)

            'bal = bal + 1
            'Sheets("Hair").Range("B" & lastrows) = field1
            'Sheets("Hair").Range("E" & lastrows) = comp
            'Sheets("Hair").Range("F" & lastrows) = name
            'Range("A" & lastrows & ":H" & lastrows).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
            'lastrows = lastrows + 1
            'countbad = countbad + 1
        End If
```

Next rCell
Next i

`

Any suggestions,

Thank you,

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried so far. Give us an idea about your data size. The `.find` method is a good start, you actually *should* waste some time on that.

Comment: There is no one *best way*.  Many factors will affect the efficiency of all the different approaches you could take (number of records in the list, type of data contained within the list, etc etc).  Prototyping and testing are not a waste of your time.  You'll need to experiment to find the solution that works best for you.

Comment: Hello @DavidG I have updated with the code i have tried, also I am dealing with around 40 - 50 items in a listbox to compare against around 5000 rows of data, Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the Reason, but, does this help?

```
Sub Weiter_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim varTemp As Variant

    varTemp = ListBox1.List '<-- for listboxes with one column. you have to edit this to pass your code

    For i = LBound(varTemp) To UBound(varTemp)
        If Columns("A:A").Find(varTemp(i, 0)) Is Nothing Then '<--- there is the column you're looking in
            Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = varTemp(i, 0)
        Else
            Columns("A:A").Find(varTemp(i, 0)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '<--- 3 is red, idk what color you want
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Pearli this is somewhat of what I need but I want to leave the ones that are found and give them a color and the rest that isnt found to be added to the bottom of the sheet,Thank you for your help aswell.

Comment: hi @AshleyDavies, i've edited my answer. There is the change of the background color of items which are already in column a.